# Why can't we derive the formula for surface area of a sphere thus?

Tags: calculus, integration, fake-proofs

I thought of deriving the formula for the surface area of a sphere using integration.

So, below are my calculations:- 
S.A. of sphere = 2 × S.A. of a hemisphere

*Now thinking of each of the hemisphere as being made up of an infinite number of circles having their radii in the range r= R to r=0 and knowing that circumference of a circle* = $2 \pi r$, **we have**$:$
$$S.A. = 2× \int_R^0 2 \pi r \,dr$$
   $= 2× ( \pi R^2 - 0) $
  $= 2\pi R^2$

Why is my derivation wrong?

Comment: In this way you are finding the projection area of the hemisphere, which is of course, $\pi R^2$.

Comment: @velutluna, can you tell me why isn't my 'proof' doing what I intended it to do? What is wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: @samjoe, so what do I need to do *basically*?

Comment: You can cutting it into ribbons. But the width of the ribbon is not $dr$.

Comment: @MrReality I recommend you to first learn proper usage of infinitesimals. Here, you first need to find a small *general* area element on hemisphere.

Comment: @velutluna, "*But the width of the ribbon is not dr*" - I don't understand why $\,dr$ matters here. Since, we're interested in only the circumference of the circles, why do we care about the width of the ribbons?

Comment: You are using circumference times width = Area to get $2\pi r dr$, aren't you?

Comment: @velutluna, actually I was confused about that. I had an idea about summing up all the circumferences but didn't know what implications using $\,dr$ has, I just plugged that in to carry on with the integral.

Comment: @velutluna, I had thought this derivation would be simple but I guess I'll have to learn more on this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This computation fails for basically the same reason as the false proof that $\pi=4$. You find find many explanations on the Internet by searching for “pi equals 4” or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

You need infinitesimal "ribbon" areas. Now it's ok to construct these areas as the circumfence $2 \pi r$ times their height d$h$. Note that this height is not d$r$ (then the ribbon would lie flat - that's why you get two times the area of a *circle* with your integration). Since the ribbon is slanted, a simple drawing of two similar triangles shows that

$$
\frac{d h }{d r}= \frac{R}{\sqrt{R^2 - r^2}}
$$

So the total surface area, as you already started, is

$$S.A. = 2× \int_{h(r=R)}^{h(r=0)} 2 \pi r \,dh = 2× \int_R^0 2 \pi r \frac{R}{\sqrt{R^2 - r^2}} dr
$$

Now you can integrate this, using the substitution $r = R \sin \phi$:

$$S.A. = 2× \int_0^{\pi/2} 2 \pi R^2 \sin \phi \, d \phi = 4 \pi R^2
$$